# Getting the key name in a loop through a map of maps in terraform

Tags: terraform

Given the following two variables in terraform:

```
variable "db_alarm_metrics" {
  type = map(any)
  description = "Database metrics to create alarms for"
  default = {
    "ReadIOPS" = {
      "threshold" = "20",
      "period" = "60000"
    },
    "WriteIOPS" = {
      "threshold" = "20",
      "period" = "60000"
    }
  }
}
```

```
variable "aggregation_db_primary_db_instance_id" {
  type        = string
  description = ""
  default = "mysql-aggregation"
}
```

I want to loop through a kind of nested for_each for the two of them, so I made the following local resource to create a list of the two combined for me to loop through.

```
locals {
  instance_metrics = flatten([
    for instance_type in [ var.aggregation_db_primary_db_instance_id, "${var.aggregation_db_primary_db_instance_id}-replica" ] : [
      for metric in var.db_alarm_metrics : {
        instance_type = instance_type
        metric = metric
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

In `terraform console` if I run `local.instance_metrics` to test the output of this, I get

```
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation"
    "metric" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation"
    "metric" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation-replica"
    "metric" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation-replica"
    "metric" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
```

Instead of "metric" as the key for those inner maps, I want the key name from `var.db_alarm_metrics`. Expected output:

```
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation"
    "ReadIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation"
    "WriteIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation-replica"
    "ReadIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
  {
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation-replica"
    "WriteIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
  },
```

What am I doing wrong? TIA!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with a slight adjustment:

```
  instance_metrics = flatten([
    for instance_type in [var.aggregation_db_primary_db_instance_id, "${var.aggregation_db_primary_db_instance_id}-replica"] : [
      for type, metric in var.db_alarm_metrics : {
        instance_type = instance_type
        "${type}"     = metric
      }
    ]
  ])
```

Note that you can reference the metric type since the variable `db_alarm_metrics` is a map as well. This gives the following output in the terraform console:

```
> local.instance_metrics
[
  {
    "ReadIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation"
  },
  {
    "WriteIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation"
  },
  {
    "ReadIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation-replica"
  },
  {
    "WriteIOPS" = {
      "period" = "60000"
      "threshold" = "20"
    }
    "instance_type" = "mysql-aggregation-replica"
  },
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved it for me. Interesting that terraform thinks this is an interpolated-only variable in 0.13
```> Warning: Interpolation-only expressions are deprecated

  on main.tf line 738, in locals:
 738:         "${type}"     = attribute```

Comment: Hm, I will check if only type works and update the answer if so. Thanks for pointing this out.